# Bevel modifier went in the wrong direction

Tags: bevel, boolean-modifier

Practicing blender. Created object, cut with boolean a hole, and when I adding bevel it's not beveling like in tutorial video.
I already done - apllied size and transformations, done clean up by distance.
What I got after adding bevel:[image]:

What I should get (from tutorial): [image]

My file
[image]

Comment: the topology is messy here, you have edges overlapping faces... it's hard to guess how it is supposed to do, maybe delete these faces to clean a bit and rebuild the topology: https://zupimages.net/up/22/45/pvau.jpg

Comment: @moonboots -- inverted face normals ... see my Answer

Comment: I edited your title based on my findings.

Comment: ok, nice if you understood what was hapening  ;)

Comment: @moonboots -- I'm matriculating in *blender forensics*, combined with *mind reading terse postings* (actually this one not too bad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, without the *pre-applied*, I couldn't completely correct, but could understand what happened.  I saw the vertices of the errant bevel inside and pulled them outward as you had hoped for.   I took a look at *Normals* and *Face Orientation* and saw that the orientation was somehow inverted (red is inner, blue is outer surface), is why the bevel went in the wrong direction.

[image]

The normals need to be inverted:

[image]

In the future, you would want to select these surface and menu >> Mesh >> Normals >> Flip:

[image]

... then the bevel would behave as desired.

Comment: U are a god. thank you